# Mysql join not getting proper values

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables

1. movies_detais
2. movies_revies
3. movies_gossips

What I want is that I want all the data whose `movies_relesed_type=0` and `movies_type=1`

But I am not getting desired values

Code

```
Select md.movies_name,
       md.movies_description,
       mr.rt_user_comments,
mg.gossip_desc
from movies_details md
Inner join movies_reviews mr
on md.movies_id=mr.movie_review_id
Inner join movies_gossips mg
on md.movies_id=mg.movies_gossip_id
and md.movie_relesed_type='0'
and md.movie_type='1'
```

With this code I am only getting one row whose `movies_relesed_type=0` and `movies_type=1`, but in my table I am having other rows also which meets the condition but they are not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a case where you want the conditions in the `where` clause:

```
Select md.movies_name,
       md.movies_description,
       mr.rt_user_comments,
       mg.gossip_desc
from movies_details md Inner join
     movies_reviews mr
     on md.movies_id=mr.movie_review_id left join
     movies_gossips mg
     on md.movies_id = mg.movies_gossip_id
where md.movie_relesed_type='0' and md.movie_type = '1';
```

A `left outer join` returns *all* the rows from the first table, even when the condition in the `on` clause evaluates to not-true.  This is true regardless of which table the conditions refer to.  So, you cannot filter on the first table in the `on` clause using a `left outer join`.

Comment: Sir i tried ur code and its working perfedctly,but also when i changed inner join to left join still the code works???

Comment: @user3917131 . . . Yes, this will work with either inner or outer joins because the filtering is done in the `where` clause.